# Convert Docx to PDF, or open docx in webview with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, io, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin.Forms app I'm writing I download a file as a byte stream. Code is as below:

```
       async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Publication p = (Publication)e.SelectedItem;
        Debug.WriteLine(p);
        if (p.folderID.Equals("-1"))
        {
            using (Stream respStream = await post(p.docNum))
            {
                string ext = p.appextension.ToLower();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[respStream.Length];
                respStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/downloadedFile." + ext;
                File.WriteAllBytes(path, buffer);
                switch (ext)
                {
                    case "pdf":
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new PDFViewPage(path));
                        break;
                    case "docx":
                        Device.OpenUri(new Uri(path));
                        break;
                    default:
                        Debug.WriteLine("wasn't pdf");
                        Debug.WriteLine("was a ." + ext);
                        break;
                }


            }
        }
        else
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new PublicationsPage(p.folderID));
        }
    }

    private async Task<Stream> post(string id)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dir = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dir.Add("LoginID", App.user.login_id);
        dir.Add("docID", id);
        var jsonReq = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dir);
        Debug.WriteLine("req: " + (String)jsonReq);
        var content = new StringContent(jsonReq, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        return responseString;
    }
}
```

Currently this works if the downloaded byte stream is a PDF, but I would like to make it work for docx aswell. User does not need to be able to edit the file. Ideally I could just open it like a PDF. Is there a way I can convert the docx byte stream into a PDF? I can't buy any packages. Or is there a way to open a docx file in a WebView in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Do you have word installed on the device or something that can open docx, if you do you can open it using that app.

Comment: I think this will work https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4845/searching-for-a-way-to-open-doc-docx